# YouTube api - IE8-9

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm trying to run YT player on my site, but there is a problem with IE8 and IE9 - player is not loading.
http://code.google.com/intl/pl/apis/youtube/youtube_player_demo.html

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    loadPlayer('{$videos[0].videoID}','{$playlist}');
}

function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
    ytplayer = document.getElementById("ytPlayer");
    ytplayer.addEventListener("onError", "onPlayerError");
    ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", 'onStateChange');
}

function loadPlayer(ytID,ytList) {
    var videoID = ytID;
    var params = {
        allowScriptAccess: "always",
        allowFullScreen: true
    };
    var atts = {
        id: "ytPlayer"
    };
    swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/" + videoID +
        "?version=3&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=player1&autohide=1&showinfo=0&autoplay=1&controls=1&loop=1&fs=1&origin=http://www._____.com&playlist="+ytList+'&key='+devKey,
        "videoDiv", "620", "350", "9", null, null, params, atts);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this causes the problem (shouldn't work on any environment), but there's a syntax error on line `3`:

```
}
```

You're not closing the `ready()`, should be:

```
});
```

Answer (score 0):

IE Does not support the addEventListener method. Try re-working that.